# Put a border on an image with css and inset it

Tags: css, border

how could I add a border around my slider here with css:

www.williamandcooper.com

to look like this:

http://williamandcooper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/slider-1.1.png

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452739/css-inset-borders

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!