# Add frame/border to image without changing image size

Tags: html, css, image, frame

I want to add a frame to my image. But with borders, the images shrink.

This is my code:

```css
.img-border {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="border border-black img-border">
</div>
<img class="img-fluid shadow bg-white" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/a3efe622972119.5631b3f61e688.gif">
```

But I feel this is very wrong.

Comment: use outline isntead of border

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Inset Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452739/css-inset-borders)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

- Use an inset `box-shadow` with `0` blur and `1px` spread. You could do this on the `img` itself to avoid the wrapper element. Shadows don't affect layout like borders do.
- Use the png as a `background-image` and set the `background-origin` to `border-box`. Give that same element the border. `background-origin` controls where the background starts drawing. ([MDN documentation for `background-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-origin))