# How to do border inside the input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, border

I have qoestion **About Input border**.

I need to create a **solid color inset border**.
I have an input And **I want To put Border Inside It** And **when I hover On it border will Get smaller**
I Found A Solution here *But It Can't Work* Becuase *I can't append span or div inside the input* to put border on it

```
        <input class="task-text" type="text" name="task" id="user-task">
```

this is the link of similar problem

<[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452739/css-inset-borders>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452739/css-inset-borders%3E)

**Any Solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```css
.task-text {
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px red;
}

.task-text:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<input class="task-text" type="text" name="task" id="user-task">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the css `outline` and the css `outline-outset` properties.

```css
input {

  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  outline-offset: -10px;

}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```