# CSS3 radio button not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, radio-button

I'm trying to style a radio button using css3 pseudo elements. In works great in chrome but it jumps back to the default styling in firefox. Any idea?

Here's a fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/pYgpt/)

The HTML:

```
<input class="fancy" name="cc1" type="radio" checked/>
<input class="fancy" name="cc1" type="radio"/>
```

The CSS:

```
input[type="radio"].fancy:before {
  content:"";
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.1),
              inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

input[type="radio"].fancy:checked:before {
  visibility: visible;
  content:"";
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.2),
          inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

input[type="radio"].fancy:checked:after {
  visibility: visible;
  content:"";
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  left: -1px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

I'm trying to avoid background-images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is not valid -- `::before` and `::after` do not work on `input` elements (any `input`; it's not just restricted to radio buttons).

Proof available here: http://jsfiddle.net/LvaE2/1/ -- even in the most simple case, it doesn't work.

It also doesn't work in IE or Opera. The fact that it does work in Chrome is because Chrome is going beyond the spec in allowing it.

Your best bet is to do your styling on a `label` element that is linked to the actual radio button using the `for` attribute, and then set the radio button itself to `display:none;`. This is how everyone else does it.

Related question here: [Which elements support the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Input radio will working in Firefox: version > 80 if added style `appearance`

```
input[type=checkbox] {   appearance:initial; }
```

Please see the Snippet:

```css
input[type=radio] {  appearance:initial; }

input[type=radio]:after{
content: "after content";
width: 100px; height: 100px; display:block;
background: red;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:after{
content: "after content";
width: 100px; height: 100px; display:block;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio"> 
<input type="radio"> 
<input type="radio">
```