# <br> and ::after or ::before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am writing a HTML-editor using content-editable and I wanted to indicate line breaks (`<br>`) with a special character ("↩") at the end of each line that ends with a `<br>`. Therefore I wanted to add a pseudo-element `::after` with that character as `content`.

```
br::after { content: ' ↩'; }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. `::before` doesn't work either.

Is there another possibility to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You might want to refer to davehauser's answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements?rq=1) thread. neither `:after` or `:before` works on elements like `img`, `br` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So probably I'll have to live with that or add an empty `<span>` in front of every `<br>`.

Comment: I guess so mate. Maybe leave the question open for some more time and see if you get any better suggestions :)

Comment: Fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this accepted answer : [Which elements support the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements?rq=1#3538529)

> As you can read here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html, :after
>   **only works on elements that have a (document tree)** content. `<input>`
>   has no content, as well as `<img>` or `<br>`.

Not funny, have you considered doing this with an image?

```
content: url(image.jpg)
```

This saying, i was designing something with ::before for a background-overlay on hover on an anchor.

I HAD to specify css content to empty {content=""} otherwize not displaying.

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to display `<br>`in an web editor.
When I add content to `<br>` it seems to get rendered differently, so that it accepts `::after`, but the normal line break gets removed.
I added it again with `::after` through the utf8 line break (\000A), but I needed to change the white space rendering so that it gets displayed.

this worked for me:

```
.htmleditor br {
    content: "&nbsp;" !important;
}

.htmleditor br::after {
    content: "→\000A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Since you mentioned this is for an web editor, I also found that adding`display: block;` to `br` can prevent the caret from flickering when starting to input.

Comment: You are a genius, '&nbsp;' in content and the !important property I did not need them tho.

Comment: doesn't work in firefox

Answer (score 2):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are vaguely defined and poorly supported for elements like `input`. Your CSS code is not invalid, just not supported in browsers and not really defined in specs.

In an editor, which must be JavaScript-driven I presume, you can simply insert “↩” characters in the DOM (and remove them later if needed). Note, however, that “ ↩” has limited font support; a small image, scaled to the font size, might work better.