# Adding characters between input fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a simple form with two columns and a field that consists of three inputs (see attached image)
[image]
The two columns are floated right.
I need to add a dash between the fields in "Adószám". I tried it with :before pseudo class but it didn't display anything. If I just add it to the HTML markup, the fields are wrapped to the next line.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="column1">
                <label for="name">Név:<br /><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></label>
                <label for="pass">Jelszó:<br /><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="1" /> Elfogadom a feltételeket
            </div>
            <div id="column2">
                <label for="email">E-mail cím:<br /><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></label>
                <label for="taxno1">Adószám:<br />
                <input type="text" id="taxno1" name="taxno1" />
                <input type="text" id="taxno2" name="taxno2" />
                <input type="text" id="taxno3" name="taxno3" />
            </label>
```

And my CSS:

```
    #column1 {
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}

#column2 {    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

input {
    width: 255px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    height: 28px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c6d1;
    background-color: #eaecf2;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#taxno1 {
    width: 82px;
}

#taxno2, #taxno3 {
    width: 46px;
    margin-left: 23px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3538529/2600397

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<div id="column1">
                <label for="name">Név:<br /><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></label>
                <label for="pass">Jelszó:<br /><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" /></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" value="1" /> Elfogadom a feltételeket
            </div>
            <div id="column2">
                <label for="email">E-mail cím:<br /><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></label>
                <label for="taxno1">Adószám:<br />
                <input type="text" id="taxno1" name="taxno1" /> -
                <input type="text" id="taxno2" name="taxno2" /> -
                <input type="text" id="taxno3" name="taxno3" />
            </label>

#taxno2, #taxno3 {
    width: 46px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/z9b5S/

Comment: Yes, I tried this but I need to maintain the total width of the 3 input fields (to be aligned with the wider input above it) on every system. And the width of the dash can be different depending on operating system and browser

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap the `input` inside a `span` and then giving a class to `span` element it will work.

```
 <div id="column2">
                <label for="email">E-mail cím:<br /><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></label>
                <label for="taxno1">Adószám:<br />

                  <span class="add"><input type="text" id="taxno1" name="taxno1" /></span>
                 <span class="add"><input type="text" id="taxno2" name="taxno2" /></span>
                 <span class="add"><input type="text" id="taxno3" name="taxno3" /></span>
            </label>
  </div>
```

And add this class in your CSS file.

```
.add:after
{
    content: "/"; 
}
.add:last-child:after{
   content: " "; 
}
```

A working Demo link is here.. http://jsbin.com/qeduhogi/3/