# Why are my <br> tags ignored by CSS counters?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

In the code below, it looks like all the `<br/>` tags are getting ignored by CSS counters. What's the reason for this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      counter-reset: ele;
    }
    *::after {
      counter-increment: ele;
      content: "element count " counter(ele);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> h1 </h1>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>

  <p><b> b </b> p</p>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, what are elements **7** and **8** representing?

Comment: [MDN Using CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) might be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Explanation of the problem(s)**

> It looks like all the `<br/>` tags getting ignored by CSS counters. The reason is?

`<br>` tags, like other 'empty' elements, [do support counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#counters), but unfortunately, they [don't have an `::after` pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements). Just like for instance `<input>` elements, you cannot pull this trick to generate content through CSS. Since incrementing the counter happens in this `::after` pseudo-element in your snippet, the counter is not incremented for `<br>` element because `br::after` simply doesn't exist.

> In the above snippet, what are elements 7 and 8 representing?"

The BODY and HTML tags. Since you use `::after`, the counter is incremented and the content inserted at the end of those elements, after the other page content.

**Half fix: Count the elements instead of the pseudo-elements**

You can change the CSS slightly to increment the counter on the element itself, and only display the value in the pseudo-element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      counter-reset: ele;
    }
    * {
      counter-increment: ele;
    }
    *::after {
      content: "element count " counter(ele);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> h1 </h1>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>

  <p><b> b </b> p</p>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

The example above doesn't quite work yet, because it doesn't increment the counter when going up a level. This is because the counter was already incremented when the element was opened, and closing the HTML and the BODY doesn't increment the counter anymore.

**Workaround: count pseudo-elements and empty elements**

Possible ways to fix it even better: Increment the counter in the `::after` after all, but add an extra piece of CSS that increments the counter for elements that don't have an `::after` pseudo-element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      counter-reset: ele;
    }
    
    /* Increment the counter in the '::after' of non-empty elements. */
    *::after,
    /* And in the element itself for empty element. 
       List taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element */
    link,track,param,area,command,col,base,meta,hr,source,img,keygen,br,wbr,colgroup,input
    {
      counter-increment: ele;
    }
    
    *::after {
      content: "element count " counter(ele);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1> h1 </h1>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>
  <h2> h2 </h2>

  <p><b> b </b> p</p>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Maybe it's not perfect for every scenario, but your question seems to be more academical anyway. 
Anyway, I hope this explanation at least helps you understand why in your snippet those `<br>` elements don't seem to have a counter at all.

Comment: Thanks it was a lot helpful!!

Comment: Sorry to nitpick but `*:not(br)::after, br {counter-increment: ele;...}` would also work :)

Comment: @harry, yes it would, but it doesn't add any value. Since br already doesn't have a `::after` pseudo-element, you could just write it as `*::after, br {counter-increment: ele;...}`, which is basically what I did in my second snippet (just included other empty elements as well, not just br). As you'll notice, I didn't list all elements there, just the empty elements.

Comment: `br` doesn't have after - this is correct but if you try `*::after, br{}` you'd see that the value increments twice for the `br` elements. UA seems to increment the value *thinking* there is an after. And yes, you did include all self closing tags, I was just saying this would be shorter )

Comment: That contradicts OP's findings. Maybe there is a difference between browsers? I'm using Chrome here.

Comment: Well I just saw that while executing the snippet in Chrome.

Comment: @Harry Can you explain your findings a bit more please?

Comment: @student: When you use the selector `*::after, br{}` to increment the counter, the UA is incrementing the counter two times for each `br` element. This seems to indicate that the UA is incrementing it once for the `br` selector and once for `br::after` even though what GolezTrol said about `br` being self closing and not having a `br::after` is true.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Actually sorry, my sample wouldn't be shorter (in fact it would be longer because we have to include all in the `:not`). Interestingly `*::after, br {counter-increment: ele;} *::after {content: "element count " counter(ele);}` - this increments only once but `*::after, br {counter-increment: ele; content: "element count " counter(ele);}` - this increments twice for every `br`. May need to check further.

Comment: @Harry: The counter only increments when the box it's incremented in is generated. For example, in `::after { content: none; counter-increment: ele; }` ele never increments. Implementations of br vary *wildly* between browsers, but in the case of Chrome, it seems one can apply the content property to br.

Comment: @BoltClock: That is true but in both the samples that I posted in my prior comment, the rules are pretty much the same (that is, the `content` is there for `::after` in both and the `br` is anyway generated). I am wondering why one of them increments the counter by one while the other does by two.

Comment: The `br` is always generated, but `br::after` is not. You can try to give it content as much as you want, but it simply doesn't exist. `*::after` doesn't apply to `br` elements.

Comment: @GolezTrol: But it still doesn't explain the double increment. You can try with the code I gave in the earlier comment and see that it does double count. Anyway, not going to drag this further.