# ol ordered list numbers not showing in line with text

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list, for some reason, the numbers are not showing in line with the text. I've tried everything I can think of, playing around with different combinations and searching for the answer. I've included an image and the CSS - any suggestions?

[image: ol ordered list number issue]

```css
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

ol li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    width: 100%;
}

ol li a {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#currentSide a {
   color: #fff;
   background: #05668d;
   width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

ol li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #05668d;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.leftInfoBox {
    width: 240px;
    top:0;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftInfoBox">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include the HTML and CSS in your snippet to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Best guess without a demo is the `align-items:center` - Remove that.

Comment: @rawnewdlz This is it, reproduced in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnbse3fv/

Comment: @Paulie_D Unfortunately that doesn't affect the number position

Comment: Full code **in the question please** not a separate link....and where is the number *supposed* to be? But my best answer is to use CSS Counters and position the marker where you need it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607940/how-do-css-counters-work

Comment: @Paulie_D just added the HTML to the question. The number is supposed to be inline where the start of the text is -- not to the top left

Comment: Your code appears to be incomplete. Your CSS starts partway through.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, not sure how I missed that but it just cut the 'ol {' tag off the start

Comment: You're floating both the li elements, and the a elements inside them, for what seems like no reason. So they are moving to new lines. Remove both floats and it will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks TylerH and @Manjuboyz, that solves the centring issue, but is there a way to get the numbers 'inside' the boxes so they are part of the link?

Comment: @Joseph You need to put the background on the `ol` or the `div` container if you want the numbers to be covered by the background.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the making it in the center, then you can do this:

> 1. `float` will indeed make the alignment off and it is not good for responsiveness, I am not sure why are you doing so many code to make it align and for `hover`.
> 2. you can use `counter-reset` to have within the `li` element and make `list-style-type: none;` this is kind of cheat code but it works in all case.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.leftInfoBox {
  width: 240px;
}

ol li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  display: block;
}

ol li:hover {
  background: #05668d;
  display: block;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div class="leftInfoBox">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Manjuboyz, I appreciate that. Ideally I would like the numbers to be part of the clickable link, but I can't get that to work and now I think about it maybe it's just not possible with ol, li etc. But thank you, that's better than I managed!

Comment: There are always limitations and there will be always cheat code too, it all depends on how you want it to be, I just coded for your requirement. Glad it helped cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `float:left` on your `li` and `a` element, and it will fix your problem.

```css
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

ol li {
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 0;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    width: 100%;
}

ol li a {
    /* float: left; */
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#currentSide a {
   color: #fff;
   background: #05668d;
   width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

ol li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #05668d;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.leftInfoBox {
  width: 240px;
  top:0;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftInfoBox">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesper Martinez that's looking good, but is it possible to get the numbers inside the grey box so they are part of the link?

Comment: @Joseph No, that's not possible to put inside to your `anchor` element if that was your method to be used. But anyway you can easily achieve that using `ul` element not on `ol`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ordered or Unordered list in html file like this :

```
<p>Example of unordered lists:</p>
    <ul class="a">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="b">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ul>

    <p>Example of ordered lists:</p>
    <ol class="c">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ol>

    <ol class="d">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Coca Cola</li>
    </ol>
```

You can also style ordered/unordered list in css file like this,these are some available ordered & Unordered list styles

```
ul.a {
  list-style-type: circle;
}

ul.b {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ol.c {
  list-style-type: upper-roman;
}

ol.d {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use line-height for your li tag.

```css
  ol {
        margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: auto;
      }
      
      ol li {
          float: left;
          margin: 0;
        background: #e5e5e5;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 50px;
      }
      
      ol li a {
          float: left;
          color: #000;
          text-decoration: none;
          padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
          height: 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      }
      
      #currentSide a {
         color: #fff;
         background: #05668d;
         width: calc(100% - 40px);
      }
      
      ol li a:hover {
          color: #fff;
          background: #05668d;
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
      }
      
      .leftInfoBox {
        width: 240px;
        top:0;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        float: left;
      }
```

```html
<div class="leftInfoBox">
        <ol>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove "display:flex" from "ol li a".

```css
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}

ol li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    width: 100%;
}

ol li a {
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 20px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    align-items: center;
}

#currentSide a {
   color: #fff;
   background: #05668d;
   width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

ol li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #05668d;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.leftInfoBox {
    width: 240px;
    top:0;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftInfoBox">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```