# Set value of range tag to :before content

Tags: javascript, css

In this example, the value of a `<range>` tag is written to an `<output>` tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/2GhQX/

Can the value of the `<range>` tag be written to the CSS `:before` value of the same `<range>` tag?

```
input[type="range"]:before {
    content: <insert value here>
}
```

Resorting to JavaScript is acceptable if necessary.

Comment: `input` tags are self-closing tags and they **cannot have pseudo-elements** attached to them (but I think there were browser inconsistencies in the past).

Comment: This works in Safari: input[type="range"]:before {content: attr(min);}

Comment: But it is not supposed to work (and so it may be scrapped anytime without you realizing it). [Reference SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Then the whole question is meaningless, really, and I should resort to using the JS Fille example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript to write the value to a custom attribute of the `input` tag and then use the the [CSS `attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function to grab the value of that attribute and populate the pseudo element's content.

```js
document.getElementById("range").addEventListener("input",function(){
  this.dataset.value=parseInt(this.value.trim());
},0);
```

```css
*{color:#000;font-family:arial,sans serif;}
input::before{
  content:attr(data-value);
}
```

```html
<input data-value="0" id="range" type="range" value="0">
```

Another option, with better future proofing, would be to use the [`output`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) element with a similar bit of JavaScript, like so:

```js
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("input",function(){
  document.getElementById("output").value=this.value.trim();
},0);
```

```css
*{color:#000;font-family:arial,sans serif;}
output{float:left;}
```

```html
<input data-value="0" id="input" type="range" value="0">
<output for="input" id="output">0</output>
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this. You learn something new every day. Best solution so far. (Even though using the pseudo-element will be obsolete in the future.)

Comment: @forthrin, I've added another option for you that doesn't rely on continued browser support for the pseudo element on the `input` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this.to dynamically apply styles,you can append new style tag with modified value as css content property value for a desired selector.

```js
$('#rangeInput').on('input', function() {
  $('body').append('<style>input[type="range"]:before{content: "' + this.value + '";}</style>');
});
```

```css
input[type="range"]:before {
  content: '0'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
      <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100">

      <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
    </form>


  </body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, obviously writing directly to the style sheet will work :) However, it does not update until letting go of the slider. Is it possible to have it update continuously while sliding? (And if possible, without writing plain text to the style sheet.)

Comment: try the edited snipped.. changed the `change` event to `input`