# CSS pseudo selectors ::before and ::after will not displayed in FF 44 and IE11

Tags: forms, css, internet-explorer, firefox, pseudo-element

To style inputs of type "**checkbox**" and "**radio**" if they are mandatory I created some css information:

```css
input[type=checkbox].is-mandatory::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    border: solid 1px #A94442;
 border-radius: 4px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    content: "";
}

input[type=checkbox].is-mandatory::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: -4px;
    border: solid 4px #F2DEDE;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input class="is-mandatory" type="checkbox" id="chk0" name="chk0" value="0">
        A simple checkbox (mandatory)
    </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input class="is-mandatory" type="radio" id="chk1" name="chk1" value="1">
        A radio (mandatory)
    </label>
</div>
```

Unfortunately it seems only displayed in Chrome and not in FF44 and IE11

[styled checkbox and radio in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecyP6.jpg)

Is there someting missing in css declaration to get the same view in IE and FF like in Chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements. Pseudo-elements are not supposed to work on `input` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that while an input can't have a :before and :after pseudo-element, the LABEL can. Set your label to have a "for" attribute that's equal to the name/id of your input, and it might help solve some issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Meanwhile I had solved the problem like you recommended by using a :before and :after with the "<label>" of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but Pseudo elements doesn't support on input. Please check the link below but i am not pretty sure that this is gonna help you

http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/