# Styling the ::before element on a mat-expansion-panel-header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kxgmi3?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) I'm trying to style the `mat-expansion-panel-header`'s `::before` pseudo element like this (Style rules added to styles.scss):

```
mat-expansion-panel-header {
  position: relative;
}

mat-expansion-panel-header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: black;
}
```

So if the above rule would take effect the `mat-expansion-panel-header` items in the demo would just be black.

However the rule does not take effect and when I look in the developer tools I don't see the `::before` element.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is the HTML just for reference:

```
<mat-accordion>
<!-- #docregion basic-panel -->
<!-- #docregion hide-toggle -->
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
<!-- #enddocregion hide-toggle -->
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
<!-- #enddocregion basic-panel -->
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Not everything is allowed to have before/after pseudo-elements, so: have you confirmed whether that custom element can even _have_ a `::before` or `::after`?

Comment: I have no idea why `mat-expansion-panel-header` doesn't accept a `::before` pseudo and it would be interesting to find out. But if you change it to `::after`, it seems to work just fine. Also note you can replace `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0` with `inset: 0`.

Comment: Oh interesting - Thanks Tao!  ... hmmm ... I also looked up what elements should support before and after selectors and it seems like it should work fine in general ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538506/which-elements-support-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Comment: You can't place them on replaced content (e.g: `<img />`, `<video />`, `<embed />`, etc...) but `mat-expantion-panel-header` is not replaced content. You might want to open a question on Angular's repo!? Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kxgmi3-fn8ngg?file=src%2Fstyles.scss), btw...

Comment: Yes it's strange ... the `::after` selector works for me locally as well ...

Comment: Sure - Just added it at the bottom ...

Comment: Works here https://plnkr.co/edit/NWRUtJ6RcQBTp9cm?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if it is something specific to Angular ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS syntax allows you to put the `::before` pseudo element inside `mat-expansion-panel-header`

[Here's a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kxgmi3-zjgjjs?file=src%2Fstyles.scss).

```scss
mat-expansion-panel-header {
  position: relative;
  ::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

Is this how it's supposed to look?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Saul if you can get it to work in the demo that would help a lot ...

Comment: Added an image of what I got. Is that what you need?

Comment: A link to a fork of this demo that works would be terrific ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/kxgmi3?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Hope it helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/kxgmi3-zjgjjs?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Comment: Wow!!  Cool!!  It looks like it works ... Interesting ... Nice work Saul and welcome to SO.

Comment: @SaulMartinez images are frowned upon, do not post images, maybe downvotes wont happen! BTW it wasn't me who downvoted!